# Programmatically add dependencies for a Jar task

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm creating a Gradle plugin that must compile the output of the SwaggerCodegen lib (a Java source tree). Inside my apply() function of my plugin, I define a  swaggerClient source set and configuration:

```
    project.sourceSets {
        swaggerClient {
            java {
                srcDirs new File(javaGenTask.outputDirectory, 'src/main/java').absolutePath
            }
        }
    }

    project.configurations {
        swaggerClient
    }
```

Then, I parse the generated build.gradle file for its dependencies, get a list of strings (with the configurations) and add them to the configuration:

```
//t instanceof List<String>, with entries in dependency markup such as:
//io.github.robwin:swagger2markup:0.9.1

    project.configurations.getByName('swaggerClient') { Configuration conf ->
        conf.dependencies.addAll t.collect {String s -> project.dependencies.create s}
    }
```

After this I define a Jar-type task:

```
    project.task('Koos',
            description: 'Generate a java jar using Swagger markup',
            type: Jar,
            dependsOn: javaGenTask) {
        from project.sourceSets.asMap['swaggerClient'].output
    }
```

The javaGenTask is the task that generates the Java source.

When running the task, none of the declared dependencies are there, resulting in compiler 'package <> doesn't exist' errors (resulting in compile failures).

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself. The configuration name + 'Compile' needs to change 

    `project.configurations.getByName('swaggerClientCompile') { Configuration conf ->
        conf.dependencies.addAll t.collect {String s -> project.dependencies.create s}
    }`

Note the 'swaggerClient' versus 'swaggerClientCompile'